# Deleting empty fields in pipe delimited printout in perl?

Tags: perl, line, pipe, delimiter, delimited

I'm going through each line of a file, looking for a few specific things in each line with regex, and I want to print it so that each row of the output .csv file just contains those things (`thing1|thing2|thing3|thing4|`) but because it's going through line by line I get things like

```
||||
```

then

```
|||thing4|
```

then

```
|thing1||thing3||
```

and I don't know how to delete the empty pipe delimited areas to shove everything together. Help?

Comment: like thing1|thing2|thing3|thing4 on row one, thing1.1|thing2.1|thing3.1|thing4.1 on row two, et cetera. I've only been programming for like two weeks.

Comment: @user2471806 Here's what your question says: "I want 1,2,3,4 but because of something it becomes something else. How should I fix it?" How do you expect anyone to be able to answer your question? Show the input and the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter it after with a regex

`$out =~ s/\|{2}/|/sg;`

Comment: The program so far has lots of regexes to find the things, and then it has the command (paraphrased slightly) print OUT "$thing1|$thing2|$thing3|$thing4|\n";

Comment: so where exactly would I filter the $out stuff?

Comment: Test this regex against `"a|||b"`.  `/s` has no purpose here.  Try: `s/\Q||/|/ while /\Q||/`.  Which still reduces a completely empty record to two empty fields.